# Setting Django/MySQL site to use UTF-8

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8

I want to set my Django site to use UTF-8 for MySQL in a foolproof way, regardless of whether the MySQL installation uses UTF-8 as its default.   In addition to creating the tables with UTF-8 encoding, I added the following to my database initialization in settings.py to ensure the connection is also using utf-8:

```
'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB; SET names "utf8"' }
```

This results in an error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

What is the right way to do this? Is there another place where the SET NAMES needs to be executed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need only using SET once only and appending others commands as:

```
'SET storage_engine=INNODB,character_set_connection=utf8,collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Answer (score 12):

All I had to do was put this in `settings.py`:

```
'OPTIONS': { 'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB' }
```

Then I created the database myself in MySQL with:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

followed by all the `CREATE USER` and `GRANT` calls.

After that, `./manage.py syncdb` and  `./manage.py migrate` (since I use South) finished everything up.

It's been working fine so far. Didn't have to change any MySQL config files, either. (The sysadmin wanted to keep MySQL using the `latin1` charset by default for the other users.)

Comment: Good for me, change it on db create.

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1193, "Unknown system variable 'storage_engine' How to proced?

Comment: @Joannis Sorry for the later reply, but IIRC later versions of MySQL dropped the storage_engine variable and default to InnoDB, so you can drop the init_command option and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Check: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/28/terrible-choices-mysql/

```
  'SET '
                'storage_engine=INNODB,'
                'character_set_connection=utf8,'
                'collation_connection=utf8_bin,'
                'SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED',
         }
```