# MySQL Incorrect string value error

Tags: mysql, configuration, character-encoding, warnings, non-ascii-characters

In a Django application with MySQL DB back-end users try to insert notes which contain some smileys and hearts and stuff which are Unicode characters. MySQL refuses the operations with an error:

```
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x9D\\xA4\\xEF\\xB8\\x8F' for column 'note' at row 1")
```

(The column in question has `longtext` type. The Unicode characters in this case valid, it's a heart and a modifier https://codepoints.net/U+2764 https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F, so it's not that they would be 4 byte long UTF-8 characters. I made sure that MySQL's default character set is utf-8.)

What is interesting is that I cannot fully reproduce this error on my local developer environment. One particular difference is that it only emits a warning for that anomaly.

---

Update1:

This is still bothering to me:

```
mysql> SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name="sblive";
+----------------------------+
| default_character_set_name |
+----------------------------+
| latin1                     |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I converted the specific table's charset to utf-8:

```
mysql> alter table uploads_uploads convert to character set utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1209036 rows affected (1 min 10.31 sec)
Records: 1209036  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE table_schema = "sblive" AND table_name = "uploads_uploads" AND column_name = "note";
+--------------------+
| character_set_name |
+--------------------+
| utf8               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%colla%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci   |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for `❤️` followed by a "non-spacing" "VARIATION SELECTOR-16".

- Your bytes are utf8 -- good
- Your connection needs to specify utf8 -- does it?
- Your `TEXT` column need to be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` -- is it?  Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify.
- If you are using HTML, it needs to say `charset=UTF-8` -- does it?

Suggest you switch to `utf8mb4` if the 'back-end users' are likely to enter more emoticons -- the 'Emoji' will need it.

**Addenda**

Let's check the data... Please run this

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

Those two character should deliver hex `E29DA4` and `EFB88F`.  If you see `C3A2C29DC2A4C3AFC2B8C28F`, you have "double encoding", which is a messier problem.  `2764FE0F` would indicate utf16, I think.

Comment: I made sure that the specific table is UTF-8 with `alter table table_name convert to character set utf8;`. The HTML is a REST API request and the payload comes in JSON. I tried to specify charset in the header (`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`), but it didn't affect the situation (technically in the payload those characters come in UTF-16 encoded BTW).

Comment: I added configuration to the server to default everything to UTF-8. The `character_set_database` (`show variables like "character_set_database";`) is still `latin1` though (note: after I defaulted everything I could to UTF-8 explicitly in the config file I restarted the server). However now the table's and the particular column's charset should override that to UTF-8, isn't it?

Comment: Where is utf-16 coming from?  That is inconsistent with utf8 (but it can be converted.)

Comment: Do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` -- 3 of them need to be utf8, and _database is not important.

Comment: I updated the question with some details. I still stuck with the same error. Should I worry about this: `SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name="sblive";` returns `latin1`

Comment: I also tried setting connection charset and others according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681831/setting-django-mysql-site-to-use-utf-8 If I try to set it to utf8, the server goes down. But I don't think anyway it's good to set it to utf-8, if every other table besides the one I upgraded to utf8 is latin1.

Comment: The _database_ charset is the _default_ when creating any new table in that database.  Changing the database charset does not affect any tables, much less any columns in the tables.

Comment: When you create a table, explicitly provide the `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` for the columns in that table.  Existing tables have whatever charset they have; you have to do something with each table (or the columns in the table) to change them.  Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what settings exist for a table.